# builder() in CEntity cannot override builder() in BEntity

Tags: java, lombok

I get this error when am trying to use inheritance for some builders in Lombok.

To give you some context - AEntity is the parent of the BEntity class, and BEntity is the parent of the CEntity class.

```
error: builder() in CEntity cannot override builder() in BEntity
    @Builder
    ^
  return type CEntityBuilder is not compatible with BEntityBuilder
```

Here it is the **AEntity** class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class AEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private Integer x;
    private Integer y;

}
```

And the **BEntity** class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class BEntity extends AEntity {
    private Double z;
    @Builder
    public BEntity(AEntity aEntity, Double z) {
        super(aEntity.getId(), aEntity.getX(), aEntity.getZ());
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```

Finally here it is the **CEntity** class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class CEntity extends BEntity {
    private Float w;
    @Builder
    public CEntity(BEntity bEntity, Float w) {
        super(bEntity.getZ());
        this.w = w;
    }

}
```

I also tried somethig like this, to solve the issue:

```
public static class BEntityBuilder extends AEntityBuilder{
    BBuilder() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are using Lombok version 1.18 or higher use the `@SuperBuilder` annotation. Worth a read: https://www.baeldung.com/lombok-builder-inheritance

Comment: If I do that I will get this error: ```BEntityBuilder does not take parameters```

Answer (score 0):

Some method signatures are colliding. Let's see what Lombok is trying to generate for EntityB:

```
public class BEntity extends AEntity {
    private Double z;

    public BEntity(AEntity aEntity, Double z) {
        super(aEntity.getId(), aEntity.getX(), aEntity.getZ());
        this.z = z;
    }
    
    public BEntityBuilder builder() {
        return new BEntityBuilder();
    }

    class BEntityBuilder {
        // builder pattern using the specified fields
    } 
}
```

Now, let's do the same for EntityC:

```
public class CEntity extends BEntity {
    private Float w;
    
    public CEntity(BEntity bEntity, Float w) {
        super(bEntity.getZ());
        this.w = w;
    }

    public CEntityBuilder builder() {
        return new CEntityBuilder();
    }

    class CEntityBuilder {
        // builder pattern using the specified fields
    }
}
```

As you can see, they are both declaring the `builder()` method, but with different return types. Therefore, because `CEntity` is extending `BEntity`, there will be a compilation error.

In other words, `CEntity` cannot have both it's own builder() returning CEntityBuilder as well as inherit the builder method from the parent, returning BEntityBuilder.

To prevent this, you need to change one of the builder methods. Lombok allows you to do it using this attribute `builderMethodName`. For instance:

```
public class CEntity extends BEntity {
    private Float w;
    @Builder(builderMethodName = "centityBuilder")
    public CEntity(BEntity bEntity, Float w) {
        super(bEntity.getZ());
        this.w = w;
    }
}
```

Now, the resulting class will expose both builder() (returning parent builder) and centityBuilder() which will return the current builder.

Comment: Ok, so I guess I have to not use the builder pattern here for this and try to do it in the "classic" way. Or there is another way to do it?

Comment: you can do it by changing the builder method name, with `@Builder(builderMethodName = "centityBuilder")`. I have updated the answer now

Comment: If I do that I will get this syntax error: ```Cannot resolve method 'bEntity' in 'BEntityBuilder'```. To understand what I am saying please **look here**: https://pastebin.com/Fy8MCAvZ